# For loop not performing last function in array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

The last function in the boxFill() array is not being performed. I've tried accounting for the length of the array but to no luck. (I'm very new to js, just saying). It iterates through the first four indices, and always does not perform the last index, even when I change the position of the index.

```
var pResult1 = document.getElementById("result1");
 var pResult2 = document.getElementById("result2");
 var pResult3 = document.getElementById("result3");
 var pResult4 = document.getElementById("result4");
 var pResult5 = document.getElementById("result5");
 var pResult = [pResult1,pResult2,pResult3,pResult4,pResult5]

 function checkBox() {
    /*var aFlor = [2.8,"Florida","Science"];   
    var bGeo = [3.5,"Georgia","Business"];
    var cTex = [2.3,"Texas","Health"];
    var dNew = [4.2,"NewYork","Law"];
    var eMic = [3.9,"Michigan","Humanities"];*/
    var boxValue = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
    var boxFill = [
      function(){listBox('1','Florida state Scholarship','3.5','Florida','Applied Sciences')},
      function(){listBox('2','Great Achievers Scholarship','4.0','Texas','Health')},
      function(){listBox('3','Helpful Future Scholarship','3.0','Georgia','Business')},
      function(){listBox('4','Never Give Up Scholarship','2.0','Michigan','Humanities')},
      function(){listBox('5','Times Square Talent Scholarship','3.5','New York','Law')}
    ]

  if  (boxValue.includes("f")) {
       for (i=0;i<boxFill.length+1;i++) {
        boxFill[i]();
       }
function listBox(number,name,gpa,state,major) { 
    pResult[number].innerHTML = 
"<dl><dt>"+number+". "+name+"</dt><dd>- minimum GPA is: "+gpa+"</dd><dd>- You must live in "+state+"</dd><dd>- For the "+major+" major!</dd></dl>";
 }
```

Is there a direct problem with the for loop or is it something in the array itself?

Comment: `i<boxFill.length+1` should be `i<boxFill.length`.

Comment: There are also more straightforward ways of accomplishing what I think you want to do, using an array of objects and a single function to output your data, rather than 5 functions and manually numbering each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i<boxFill.length+1` should be `i<boxFill.length`, otherwise your loop iterates one more time than there are elements.

The function gets called, but it will throw an error because it tries to access an index in `pResult` that doesn't exist. If you open your browser's console you should see an error such as

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Arrays are *zero-indexed* in JavaScript. That means that `pResult[0]` will access the first element, `pResult[1]` accesses the second element, etc.

Now, the last function in `boxFill` tries to access `pResult[5]`, i.e. the sixth element. But `pResult` only has five elements!

You need pass the values `0` to `4` to `listBox`, not `1` to `5`:

```
var boxFill = [
  function(){listBox(0,'Florida state Scholarship','3.5','Florida','Applied Sciences')},
  function(){listBox(1,'Great Achievers Scholarship','4.0','Texas','Health')},
  function(){listBox(2,'Helpful Future Scholarship','3.0','Georgia','Business')},
  function(){listBox(3,'Never Give Up Scholarship','2.0','Michigan','Humanities')},
  function(){listBox(4,'Times Square Talent Scholarship','3.5','New York','Law')}
]
```

Or if you want to pass `1-5` then you need to subtract `1` when accessing the index:

```
pResult[number-1].innerHTML = ...;
```

Comment: Or call `boxFill[i + 1]()` (and do the -1 bit later). ;-)